# T-SQL -- find rows with one column value that are associated with multiple value occurrences of another column

Tags: t-sql, search, group-by, query-optimization, sql-server-2014

**T-SQL -- find rows with one column value that are associated with multiple value occurrences of another column.**

The goal is to find occurrences of table1.col1 values that have multiple values for table1.col2.  (NOTE:  The value in either table is not fixed, e.g. we are not searching for a pattern such as "ABC", but has to be a specific value.)

(`Group by` would find **pairs** of (col1,col2) tuples that are the same.  )

I actually have some code that I think is theoretically correct but runs very, very slowly on my system:

```
-- find examples where the 1st-column value exists on more than one second-column value to test this. 

Select TOP 10 [Col_1], count(1) as countRows_outer from
(
    SELECT [Col_2]
          ,[Col_1]
          ,count(1) as countRowsInner

      FROM [OurDatabase].[dbo].[OurTable]
      WHERE 
      (
        (Col_1 is not null)
        and
        (len (Col_1) > 0)
      )
      group by [Col_2] ,[Col_1] -- after studying:  Inner group by *NOT* needed
      having (count(1) >= 2) -- not really needed, but limits search set, faster query results
        --order by  [Col_1],  [Col_2] -- , countRows desc
)c1
group by Col_1
having(count(1)  >= 2) -- > 1 (per answer below, may be more efficient here)
order by countRows_outer desc
```

In the above code, the inner 'having' clause is not really needed, nor are the "top" key-words, but they speed things up a bit.

Does anyone have a better way, or alternatively, a way to speed this up.

For this example, all columns are nvarchar(255).

I use SSMS 14.017 with an underlying SQL database of select @@version = Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3)

Comment: Not sure why there is a downvote here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do this with a simple GROUP BY

```
SELECT col1
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col2)> 1
```

This should get you occurrences of table1.col1 values that have multiple values for table1.col2

Comment: The inner 'group by' in my query on top is not needed, and would only count (col1, col2) pairs, hence it gets different results.  I think the answer is a better query, and works correctly, and faster.  Probably "> 1" is at least as fast as ">=2" depending on the underlying optimizer and even the compiled-machine-code as well, so good job.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect the comments above.  In any event, this answer seems good in every respect.